# Sylow's Theorem Application. Prove $G$ is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Assume that $|G|=5^27^2$. Determine the possibilities for $n_5, n_7$ and determine what can be concluded in each case about the $5$-Sylow subgroups and the $7$-Sylow subgroups and prove that $G$ is Abelian.

Proof: Assume that |G|=$5^27^2$. By Sylow's Theorem,

Then $n_5 \equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $n_5 \mid 49$. Thus $n_5 = 1$.

And $n_7 \equiv 1\pmod 7$ and $n_7 \mid 25$. Thus $n_7 = 1$.

Hence $P_5 \lhd G$ and $P_7 \lhd G$.

I am stuck on how to prove $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Can you show that each of the Sylow subgroups are abelian?

Comment: $P_5$=<a> and |a|=5 and $P_7$=<b> and |b|=7 . And every cyclic group is abelian.

Comment: Neither Sylow subgroup need to be cyclic. They have orders $25$ and $49$, not $5$ and $7$.

Comment: So |$P_5$|=5^2 and |$P_7&|=7^2 and There are theorem that says every group of whose order is square of prime is Abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know that if $p$ is a prime number, then every group of order $p^2$ is abelian? Use that and finish the proof with this one weird tip:

- If $M \trianglelefteq G$ and $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $M \cap N = 1$, then $mn = nm$ for all $m \in M$ and $n \in N$.

(you should prove this if you haven't already)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost done. $P_5\cap P_7=\{1\}$ and they together generate the whole group $G$, thus we have $G=P_5\times P_7$, as both are normal subgroups therein.

Additionally, both $P_5$ and $P_7$ has $p^2$ elements for a prime $p$, and hence they both are Abelian, because the center of a non-abelian group must not be cyclic, and a $p$-group must have nontrivial center (because of dividability reasons, having already the identity element in a separate conjugate class, there must be at least $p-1$ other elements which make their conjugate classes alone).